ACR39T card reader
I have ACR39T usb card reader, and I use it to sign official documents for online transactions. Even though I installed the manufacturer's driver, the system does not see the card reader.
2024-12-19T17:20:05.922633+03:00 MiniPC kernel: usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
2024-12-19T17:20:06.074202+03:00 MiniPC kernel: usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=072f, idProduct=b100, bcdDevice=30.15
2024-12-19T17:20:06.074212+03:00 MiniPC kernel: usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
2024-12-19T17:20:06.074213+03:00 MiniPC kernel: usb 3-4: Product: ACR39U ICC Reader
2024-12-19T17:20:06.074214+03:00 MiniPC kernel: usb 3-4: Manufacturer: ACS
2024-12-19T17:20:06.107585+03:00 MiniPC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-4"
2024-12-19T17:20:06.111699+03:00 MiniPC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
2024-12-19T17:20:06.118386+03:00 MiniPC systemd[1]: Reached target smartcard.target - Smart Card.
2024-12-19T17:20:06.118628+03:00 MiniPC systemd[3458]: Reached target smartcard.target - Smart Card.
2024-12-19T17:20:06.122837+03:00 MiniPC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-4"
2024-12-19T17:20:06.126861+03:00 MiniPC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device


There is no driver; it says none!
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 010: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 010: Dev 002, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 004: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=[none], 12M
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M

libacsccid1 is already the newest version (1.1.11-1).

do not add extra requested data to your post by using answers. EDIT your post instead to add data.

Based on the Vendor and Product ID from the output, we can determine this card is an Advanced Card Systems, Ltd (ACS) card, which should be covered under the acsccid driver package that ships in the repositories.
It is NOT, however, part of the default installation.
Install the acsccid package from the Universe pocket.
sudo apt install libacsccid1

This is the driver package you need.  Once it's installed, reboot, and see if the system recognizes the smart card reader.
